# Is there Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc - ControllerFeatureProvider for rest api (.net framework)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this class in asp.net-core-webapi and I want to implement the equivalent in asp.net-web-api.
How can I do that any help please?

```
public class C1ControllerFeatureProvider : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider
{}
```